# How to make global costmap larger in slam_karto: goal sent to the navfn planner is off the global costmap

Tags: navigation, ros-melodic, move-base, turtlebot-navigation

I am trying to send a 2D nav goal to the navigation stack of my turtlebot3, which is running slam_karto. The problem is that the global costmap is taken to be the map topic. The map topic's occupancy grid map's width and height expands as the robot moves around.

Due to not having a fixed large size global costmap, when I send a goal to outside the global costmap (i.e map topic's occupancy grid map), then I get the warning:

```
The goal sent to the navfn planner is off the global costmap. Planning will always fail to this goal.
```

The attached[image: image of the global costmap] is shown, it is exactly the local map topic. How do I expand the global costmap to be much larger, say 40x40m, in slam_karto? I have looked at various other questions but could not find an answer on how to do this with slam_karto because you cannot specify width and height for global_costmap_params.yaml with slam_karto.